# Linking CXX shared library fails - undefined reference

Tags: cmake, llvm, linker-errors

I am trying to install  the llvm compiler following their guide with the following options.
`cmake -S llvm -B build -G "Unix Makefiles" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra;compiler-rt;polly" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` and when building it I get the follwing error.

```
[ 53%] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../lib/clang/18/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libclang_rt.ubsan_standalone.so
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/RTUbsan_cxx.x86_64.dir/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp.o: in function `findBaseAtOffset(__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, long)':
/home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:174: undefined reference to `typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:174: undefined reference to `typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:174: undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:178: undefined reference to `typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:178: undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/RTUbsan_cxx.x86_64.dir/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp.o: in function `isDerivedFromAtOffset(__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, long)':
/home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:137: undefined reference to `typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:137: undefined reference to `typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:137: undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:141: undefined reference to `typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:141: undefined reference to `typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:141: undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/RTUbsan_cxx.x86_64.dir/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp.o: in function `__ubsan::checkDynamicType(void*, void*, unsigned long)':
/home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:245: undefined reference to `typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:245: undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mbelda/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_type_hash_itanium.cpp:245: undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [projects/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/CMakeFiles/clang_rt.ubsan_standalone-dynamic-x86_64.dir/build.make:257: lib/clang/18/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libclang_rt.ubsan_standalone.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:36815: projects/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/CMakeFiles/clang_rt.ubsan_standalone-dynamic-x86_64.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
```

How can I fix this?

My system is a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

I have narrowed down that the issue is with the compiler-rt option since it only gives the error if I add that option.